# How to access configuration in configureServices

Tags: f#, f#-giraffe

How would you access configuration from inside the `configureServices` method in Giraffe-FSharp?

Here's an abridged section from the Giraffe setup created by the [SAFE template](https://safe-stack.github.io/docs/quickstart/) via `dotnet new SAFE -lang F# --server giraffe`:

```
let configureServices (services : IServiceCollection) =
    services.AddCors()                  |> ignore
    services.AddGiraffe()               |> ignore
    // Want to access configuration here.



[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    let contentRoot = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
    let webRoot     = Path.Combine(contentRoot, "WebRoot")

    WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(contentRoot)
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseWebRoot(webRoot)
        .Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> configureApp)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(Action<WebHostBuilderContext, IConfigurationBuilder> configureAppConfig)
        .ConfigureServices(configureServices)
        .ConfigureLogging(configureLogging)
        .Build()
        .Run()
    0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get the service provider from the services collection, then use that to get the configuration:

```
let serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider()
let config = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>()
```

Comment: Works a treat! :)

Comment: does it work though with reloadable configs? Because the IConfiguration instance you generate inside the ConfigureServices is going to be different from the final one

Comment: @atomaras It will be whatever the configuration state is at that time.  If you need to know how it handles your specific case, I recommend trying some test cases.

Comment: For C#, this helped me figure out how to access the IConfiguration from inside ConfigureServices when NOT leveraging dependency injection and performing all configuration inside the Program.cs and nixing the Startup.cs. Here's the line of code I added inside the .ConfigureServices(...) call: `IConfiguration configuration = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IConfiguration>();`